# What does "strict order" of sequence groups mean?

Tags: standards, bnf, abnf

[3.5.  Sequence Group](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234#section-3.5) section says

> Elements enclosed in parentheses are treated as a single element,
> whose contents are strictly ordered.  Thus,
>
> ```
>     elem (foo / bar) blat
> ```
>
> matches `(elem foo blat)` or `(elem bar blat)`, and

Given **exactly one** element is allowed what exact payload does the "strictly ordered" part carry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence group `(a b c)` is just for grouping the given elements. This is used for [repetitions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234#section-3.6)
like

```
*(a b c)
```

The entries inside the sequence group must appear in the given order. Then the sequence group itself can appear/match based on other operators (like the `*` operator above).

The example shown in [3.5 Sequence Group](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234#section-3.5) is only for shown the issue between

```
elem (foo / bar) blat
```

and

```
elem foo / bar blat
```

that the `()` is needed when you want a matching of `elem foo blat` or `elem bar blat`.

Comment: Right, so it has nothing to do with `/`.